# asp.net : calculating date range for a certain period

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist having values 'today','yesterday',lastweek', 'last month', 'lastyear'.

when the user select any value from this dropdown, i want to show the from date and to date in two text boxes.

e.g. if the user selects last week, 'to date' should be today's date and 'from date' should be (today's date - 7). if current date is 12, 'from date' = 6 and 'to date' = 12

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Should be like this:

```
var toDate= DateTime.Now;
var fromDate = DateTime.Today;

switch(dropDown.SelectedValue.ToLower())
{
    case "today": fromDate = toDate; break;
    case "yesterday": fromDate = toDate.AddDays(-1); break;
    case "lastweek": fromDate = toDate.AddDays(-(int)toDate.DayOfWeek); break;
    case "last month": fromDate = toDate.AddMonths(-1); break;
    case "lastyear": fromDate = toDate.AddYears(-1); break;
    default: break;
}

ddlFrom.Text = fromDate.ToShortDateString();
ddlTo.Text = toDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: case "today": fromDate = DateTime.Today; break;

Comment: @syd: you provided an example in your question: `if the user selects last week, 'from date' should be today's date and 'to date' should be (today's date - 7)`. So it is a little bit fuzzy.

Comment: sorry, i modified the question

Comment: @syd: it seems I understand what you want - just updated my answer. Should last month and last year to be calculated in the same manner?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be something like this:

```
FromDateTextBox.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString();

if(YourDropDown.SelectedValue == "today")
  ToDateTextBox.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString();
else if (YourDropDown.SelectedValue == "yesterday")
  ToDateTextBox.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString();
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unsure if you want to have this week (today-6days till today) or today-7days. Another option would be from monday(or whenever week starts) till now, the same for month and year(maybe from 2011/01/01).

aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlTimeSpan" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlTimeSpan_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
           <asp:ListItem Text="-- select timespan --" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="today" Value="today"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="yesterday" Value="yesterday"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="last week" Value="lastweek"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="last month" Value="lastmonth"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="last year" Value="lastyear"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtFromDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>&nbsp<asp:TextBox ID="TxtToDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

codebehind:

```
 Protected Sub DdlTimeSpan_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim fromDate As Date = Date.Now
    Dim toDate As Date
    Select Case DirectCast(sender, DropDownList).SelectedValue
        Case "today"
            toDate = Date.Now
        Case "yesterday"
            toDate = Date.Now.AddDays(-1)
        Case "lastweek"
            toDate = Date.Now.AddDays(-7)
        Case "lastmonth"
            fromDate = Date.Now.AddMonths(-1)
        Case "lastyear"
            toDate = Date.Now.AddYears(-1)
    End Select
    Me.TxtFromDate.Text = fromDate.ToShortDateString
    Me.TxtToDate.Text = toDate.ToShortDateString
End Sub
```

C#:

```
protected void DdlTimeSpan_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    System.DateTime fromDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    System.DateTime toDate = default(System.DateTime);
    switch (((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue) {
        case "today":
            toDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            break;
        case "yesterday":
            toDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            break;
        case "lastweek":
            toDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
            break;
        case "lastmonth":
            fromDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            break;
        case "lastyear":
            toDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            break;
    }
    this.TxtFromDate.Text = fromDate.ToShortDateString();
    this.TxtToDate.Text = toDate.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: if the currentdate is 12. from date should be 6. but fromdate will be 5 as per your solution.

Comment: This is what OP wants: "if the user selects **last week**, 'from date' should be today's date and **'to date' should be (today's date - 7)**"